# In python, why does sys.stdout.write() behave differently between running it inside command line and running it inside a script

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems like sys.stdout.write() appends the length of the input string at the end when executed from command line. Why?

For example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write('something')
something9
>>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `write` call returns how many bytes have been written, and that is *also* echoed to `stdout`, by the interactive prompt.

You can suppress the bytes-written echo by assigning the return value of `sys.stdout.write()`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write('something')
something9
>>> bytes_written = sys.stdout.write('something')
something>>> bytes_written
9
```

Comment: or even better (if you don't care about the result) : `_ = sys.stdout.write(....`

Comment: Thank you! That explains it :D

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: in the interactive interpreter that's actually not that great an idea. `_` is a built-in there that captures the last echoed result. By setting a global `_` you mask that feature. You now hav to use `del _` to get it back. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I never realised that - thank you.